# gitweb is broken in debian jessie

Tags: debian

I had installed gitweb package in debian wheezy, and I had got it working.

After upgrading to jessie it doesn't work any more: Apache tells me:

> The requested URL /gitweb was not found on this server.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's seems that the Debian installation of Apache is not loading the configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/gitweb.conf . This may happen because your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is not loading the configuration files in that directory.

My solution was to move the gitweb.conf file to the /etc/apache2/conf.d/ directory. Of course I could have enabled the directory conf-enabled content loading, but because there where other files there that could conflict with other of my sites, I did not.

I know this is a kind of old issue, but I hope this will help others with a similar problem.